# Matplotlib Live Graph - Using Time as x-axis values

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I was just wondering if it is possible to use Time as x-axis values for a matplotlib live graph.
If so, how should it be done? I have been trying many different methods but end up with errors.
This is my current code :

```
update_label(label):

    def getvoltage():

        f=open("VoltageReadings.txt", "a+")
        readings = [0]*100
        maxsample = 100
        counter = 0

        while (counter < maxsample):

            reading = adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN)
            readings.append(reading)
            counter += 1

        avg = sum(readings)/100
        voltage = (avg * 0.1259)/100
        time = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())
        f.write("%.2f," % (voltage) + time + "\r\n")
        readings.clear()

        label.config(text=str('Voltage: {0:.2f}'.format(voltage)))
        label.after(1000, getvoltage)
    getvoltage()

def animate(i):
    pullData = open("VoltageReadings.txt","r").read()
    dataList = pullData.split('\n')
    xList=[]
    yList=[]
    for eachLine in dataList:
        if len(eachLine) > 1:
            y, x = eachLine.split(',')
            xList.append(float(x)))
            yList.append(float(y))
            a.clear()
    a.plot(xList,yList)
```

This is one of the latest method I've tried and I'm getting error that says

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '17:21:55'
```

I've tried finding ways to convert the string into a float but I can't seem to do it

I'd really appreciate some help and guidance, thank you :)

Comment: if you mean by 'live graph' an oscilloscope-like Display, imho matplotlib is not the perfect tool to go, as it's designed for publishable beauty of plots
Have a look at PyQtGraph (http://pyqtgraph.org/) - it's developed with exactly this kind of applications in mind

Comment: The live graph is supposed to show battery voltage readings along with time to analyse battery health over time

Comment: the implicit typecast float(x) is only working for strings, which contain nothing but an as a number interpretable bunch of characters. As soon as there's anything else in it (e.g. like ':') it will fail.
you already imported `datetime`, so try e.g. `datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should use the datetime library. You can read your dates using this command `date=datetime.strptime('17:21:55','%H:%M:%S')` but you have to use the Julian date as a reference by setting a `date0=datetime(1970, 1, 1)` You can also use the starting point of your time series as a date0 and then set your date as `date=datetime.strptime('01-01-2000 17:21:55','%d-%m-%Y %H%H:%M:%S')`. Compute the differences between your actual date and the reference date IN SECONDS (there are several functions to do this) for each line in your file using a loop and affect this difference to a list element (We will call this list Diff_list). At the end use `T_plot= [dtm.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(i) for i in Diff_List]`. Finally a `plt.plot(T_plot,values)` will allow you to visualize the dates on the x-axis.

You can also use the pandas library

first, define your date parsing depending on the dates type in your file `parser=pd.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Then you read your file

`tmp = pd.read_csv(your_file, parse_dates={'datetime': ['date', 'time']},                          date_parser=parser, comment='#',delim_whitespace=True,names=['date', 'time', 'Values'])`

`data = tmp.set_index(tmp['datetime']).drop('datetime', axis=1)`

You can adapt these lines if you need to represent only hours `HH:MM:SS` not the whole date.

N.B: Indexing will not be from 0 to `data.values.shape[0]` but the dates will be used as indexes. So if you want to plot you can do a `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and then `plt.plot(data.index,data.Values)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [polt Python package](https://pypi.org/project/polt) which I developed for this exact purpose. [polt](https://pypi.org/project/polt) uses [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org) to display data from multiple sources simulateneously.

Create a script `adc_read.py` that reads values from your ADC and `print`s them out:

```py
import random, sys, time

def read_adc():
    """
    Implement reading a voltage from your ADC here
    """
    # simulate measurement delay/sampling interval
    time.sleep(0.001)
    # simulate reading a voltage between 0 and 5V
    return random.uniform(0, 5)


while True:
    # gather 100 readings
    adc_readings = tuple(read_adc() for i in range(100))
    # calculate average
    adc_average = sum(adc_readings) / len(adc_readings)
    # output average
    print(adc_average)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

which outputs

```sh
python3 adc_read.py
# output
2.3187490696344444
2.40019412977279
2.3702603804716555
2.3793495215651435
2.5596985467604703
2.5433401603774413
2.6048815735614004
2.350392397280291
2.4372325168231948
2.5618046803145647
...
```

This output can then be [piped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) into [polt](https://pypi.org/project/polt) to display the live data stream:

```sh
python3 adc_read.py | polt live
```

[image: polt plot window]

Labelling can be achieved by adding metadata:

```sh
python3 adc_read.py | \
    polt \
        add-source -c- -o name=ADC \
        add-filter -f metadata -o set-quantity=voltage -o set-unit='V' \
        live
```

[image: polt plot window]

The [polt documentation](https://nobodyinperson.gitlab.io/python3-polt) contains information on possibilities for further customization.